# Automatically declaration yesod handlers using Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, yesod, template-haskell

For example, I have next entity type in Model

```
User json
    username Text
```

and following Haskell types:

```
Entity User
```

Delete handler for User:

Routes file:

```
/users/#UserId UserR DELETE
```

Handler declaration:

```
deleteUserR :: UserId -> Handler Value
deleteUserR uid = do
    runDB $ delete uid
    sendResponseStatus status200 ("DELETED" :: Text)
```

I want to write template function something like this:

```
mkDeleteHandler :: String -> Q [Dec]
mkDeleteHandler name = do
    [d|hname idname = do
        runDB $ delete idname
        sendResponseStatus status200 ("DELETED" :: Text)|]
        where hname  = mkName ("delete" ++ name ++ "R")
              idname = mkName ("i" ++ name)
```

In my Handler.User module I write

```
mkDeleteHandler "User"
```

But it is not working. Compiler write next warnings:

**Warning: Defined but not used: hname**

**Warning: Defined but not used: idname**

And Error:

**Not in scope: deleteUserR**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Simple type signature parameterization example added

I think there is a problem with function name binding in your `mkDeleteHandler`. I would try something like this for example (example simplified):

```
mkHandler :: String -> String -> Q [Dec]
mkHandler typeName funcName = do
  funDecl <- [d| funcName :: String -> IO()
                 funcName var1 = do
                 print var1 |]

  let [SigD _ (AppT _ t0), FunD _ funBody] = funDecl
      sigBody' = (AppT (AppT ArrowT (ConT tname)) t0)

  return $ [SigD hname sigBody', FunD hname funBody]

  where
    hname  = mkName funcName
    tname = mkName typeName
```

And then you can splice it something like this:

```
data Foo = Foo Int
     deriving Show

$(mkHandler "Int" "handlerInt")
$(mkHandler "String" "handlerString")
$(mkHandler "Foo" "handlerFoo")

main = do
  handlerInt 5
  handlerString "Hello World"
  handlerFoo $ Foo 5
```

Note that the `mkHandler` should be defined in separate module and imported first before using it.

Your problem was that the `hname` was not used at all, like the compiler has correctly warned. The fix is that we generate a "template" function declaration using quotation brackets and then replace the generated function name with our own `hname`.

IMHO the best tutorial for learning `Template Haskell` is [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20100703060856/http://www.haskell.org/bz/thdoc.htm).

Comment: Function declaration deleteUserR now exists in module Handler.User, but when Yesod runner try call deleteUserR from module Application, compiler write Yesod specific Error:

No instance for (ToTypedContent res0)
  arising from a use of `yesodRunner'
The type variable `res0' is ambiguous

Comment: Hi, Maybe we should add type signature to the generated function declaration. I have updated the code example in my answer. Try it again with right type signature, in your case: `funcName :: UserId -> Handler Value`

Comment: Problem: I don't know type signature for `funcName`

It have type something like this: `Key User -> Handler Value`
but type User is argument of mkDeleteHandler, where `Key User = UserId`

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea what you are exactly trying to do without seeing the full code... Can you update your question with full code?

Comment: Do you have yesod packages installed? For example, default Yesod scaffolding site enough to get error

Comment: Do you get an error too, if you define the function `deleteUserR` "manually" like you did in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69062/discussion-between-bmk-and-bet).

Comment: I've updated the answer with a simple type parametrization example. It should be straight forward to adapt the example for your case.

Comment: Very good example. It is really solve problem. Can I write code with TH something like this `funcName :: $(mytype) -> IO()`, where $(mytype) - compile time evaluation type?